# Dynamic uploaded image not shown in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application where I upload images dynamically and show them in the same page via the given script.

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("picture").innerHTML = "<img src='absolute_server_url'/>";
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="picture">
</div>
```

The problem is my image uploads successfully but the updated image is not shown in the html page.

> Image name also remains same. I mean when I upload a new image I name that image same as the previous one. May be this will create a problem.

.

Comment: Can you try `document.getElementById("picture").src=...` instead of `innerHTML` ?

Comment: Add your html code segment here

Comment: Are you have errors in your console?

Comment: Is 'picture' id use for img tag?

Comment: @Kushan, HTML added.

Comment: Where you use id 'picture'?

Comment: Since your `div` has its id as `profile`, you should be changing your `document.getElementById...` statement as, `document.getElementById("profile")`

Comment: @Kushan, typo mistakes. The DIV has a ID named picture.

Comment: @DavidR, it was a typo mistakes.

Comment: @Mysterious Okay. Is it running after you correct it?

Comment: The result is same as it is before.. Image uploaded but not loaded in html (Updated image).

Comment: @Mysterious add some timestamp to the image url to avoid cached data; like `imgUrl?t=timestamphere`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're uploading the image to the same filename this image will be potentially cached on the client.

You can get around this by [cache-busting](http://curtistimson.co.uk/front-end-dev/what-is-cache-busting/).

The simplest method in your example is to attach the current date/time as a query string.

Furthermore rather than use `innerHtml` it would be better to build your `img` element and set the `src`.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "absolute_server_url?dt=" + Date.now();
document.getElementById("picture").appendChild(img);
```

Comment: If I add this query string then is it automatically solve or I have to do something manually??

Comment: @Mysterious Should work fine, if it's a caching issue. However see my update. I hadn't realised your `picture` element was a `div`.

Comment: Let me try in my script and I will confirm you.

Comment: it throws __Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier__

Comment: @Mysterious Ah typo, missed a `+`!..... `"absolute_server_url?dt=" + Date.now();`

Comment: Opss.. I forgot to concatenate the `Date.now()`, Just copy and paste your code. But now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `.src` property instead of `.innerHTML`,

Like this,

```
document.getElementById("profile").src = "your_image_url";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a wrong information, If I use `src` then I must avoid the `img` tag.

Comment: Corrected!.. I was using whatever was there in your code sample :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
<div id="picture">
</div>

 <script>
     /* added timestamp to avoid cached data; */     
     document.getElementById("picture").innerHTML = "<img src='absolute_server_url?t=" + Date.now() + "' />";
 </script>
```

Comment: This idea works, but one little problem created, All my uploaded images now stores..... :-( :-( [I mean for the same person I upload different images with the same name but now its with different name]

Comment: @Mysterious We can't control in JavaScript that is server side issue, do check your code you are using to save image maybe you took timestamp in wrong way this is not for only this line of js code need to append after image url;

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give you UV you when I will eligible for it.

Comment: Yes, But the appropriate and descriptive answer given by Curt. So I go with him.